# How to stop the deployment project from installing the app.config file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation

I want to stop the Visual Studio deployment project from installing the app.config to the target directory.

The app.config file already has the following properties set:

- Build Action => None
- Copy to Output Directory => Do Not Copy

Upon running the installer (setup.exe) it installs the app.config to the target directory and renames it as *applicationName.exe.config*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Navigate to the deployment project in the solution explorer
- Click the "Primary Output From (Application)" item
- Under properties, set the Exclude Filter to ***.config**